# How to setup ASP.NET Web Application with Docker container

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have followed the installation instructions found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/vs-azure-tools-docker-edit-and-refresh/
and made an empty ASP.Net hello world project. I keep getting this error when I try to build my project:

```
Error   MSB3073 The command "powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned .\Docker\DockerTask.ps1 -Build -Environment Debug -Machine 'default'" exited with code 1. HelloWorld  C:\dev\HelloWorld\src\HelloWorld\Properties\Docker.targets  37
```

Upon further digging I get this error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>
1>  Build succeeded.
1>           0 Warning(s).
1>           0 Error(s).
1>
1>  Time elapsed 00:00:00.0958314
1>
1>  .\Docker\DockerTask.ps1 : The term '.\Docker\DockerTask.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
1>  script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
1>  correct and try again.
1>  At line:1 char:1
1>  + .\Docker\DockerTask.ps1 -Build -Environment Debug -Machine 'default'
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\Docker\DockerTask.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
1>
1>C:\dev\HelloWorld\src\HelloWorld\Properties\Docker.targets(37,5): error MSB3073: The command "powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned .\Docker\DockerTask.ps1 -Build -Environment Debug -Machine 'default'" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am using Visual Studios 2015 on Windows 10 64bit.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my working directory was set differently than the default settings. By using the get-location command I was able to figure out where the working directory was and give it the relative path from that directory.

```
HelloWorld\src\HelloWorld\Docker\DockerTask.ps1
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing this same issue, could you please tell me in more details how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Rightly pointed out by SirJackovich.

The issue was due to a mis-pointed folder path given to msbuild.

To check out what path to modify, follow these steps:

- In Properties\Docker.targets,

  a. Temporarily change DockerBuildCommand to `<DockerBuildCommand>powershell get-location</DockerBuildCommand>`.

  b. Temporarily change DockerCleanCommand to `<DockerCleanCommand>powershell get-location</DockerCleanCommand>`.

  c. Run build having Docker build target selected (instead of 'IIS Express').

  d. From the trace output in the Output window, it will print the folder which is the root for execution. For example, c:\folder1 is the root execution folder for powershell.

  e. Lets say DockerTask.ps1 is located in `c:\folder1\MyApp\src\App1\DockerTask.ps1`. Modify the DockerBuildCommand command  within `Properties\Docker.targets` to point to `MyApp\src\App1\DockerTask.ps1`. Also Modify the DockerCleanCommand command to point to `MyApp\src\App1\DockerTask.ps1`.

  powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned `MyApp\src\App1\DockerTask.ps1.ps1` -Build -Environment $(Configuration) -Machine '$(DockerMachineName)' -ClrDebugVersion VS2015U2

  powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned `MyApp\src\App1\DockerTask.ps1` -Clean -Environment $(Configuration) -Machine '$(DockerMachineName)'

  f. Rebuild the solution.

This will deploy the image to the `default` docker environment within docker-machine.